# AngularJs: Masked input currency max and min

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maskedinput

I am using [this](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks) git repository for my masked input for angularjs. And I am trying to use the min and max from this but I am not having any luck so far.
For example:
If I set max = 5000 and it should not exceed that number but it is not working. Here is what I am using:

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" name="field" ng-model="number" ui-money-mask />
```

So can you guys help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `max` in what you posted. Might be worth posting where it's actually set.

Comment: you appear to be trying to apply filters that are meant for `text` input boxes on a `tel` input box.  This probably won't work.

Comment: also, this isn't a question about git just because you downloaded a repository from there.

Comment: @Claies I tried applying min and max filter for text input but it is not working with that too.